# Sencha Touch 2 - Accelerometer values

Tags: sencha-touch, accelerometer

Is it possible to fetch values within the accelerometer in a phonedevice using Sencha Touch 2? Googled a bit and found a project someone did, AccelerometerTabs. I'm guessing this is something similiar to what I'm searching for, however I just want to fetch x,y and z values. After some researching I haven't found any material that says it does work so now I'm asking you more experienced Sencha Touch users - is this possible and how do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to do it with the help of `phonegap`

Comment: If I'm using PhoneGap, am I bound to creating a plattform specific function? In example, if I want the app to work on iOS, Android and BlackBerry. Do I have to build the accelerometerfunctions in 3 different versions?

Comment: You anyways have to build different installers for different OS but codewise I think phonegap should abstract it for you